# Is Savage Hulk the only one to appear in film?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I know there are many different kinds of Hulk, like Grey Hulk, Devil Hulk, Worldbreaker Hulk and so on. Do any besides Savage Green Hulk ever appear in a film? (Extra-have She Hulk or Maestro ever appeared in film?)

Comment: Define "film"....

Comment: She-Hulk is getting her own TV show on Disney+ in 2022

Answer (score 7):

As was mentioned by [@FuzzyBoots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218398/58193) already we see Smart Hulk in *Avengers: Endgame*. In the comics this version has been referred to as Merged Hulk, Professor Hulk and [Smart Hulk](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/1325/smart-hulk). However, in the MCU the official name for the character is indeed Smart Hulk:

> **KeyFeige:** We refer to the version of Hulk in Endgame as Smart Hulk. So, yes.
>
> <sub>[reddit, r/marvelstudios, Hi reddit, I'm Kevin Feige. AMAA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/enp3dlc/?context=3)</sub>

Whilst it has not happened yet Phase 4 for the MCU will feature a She-Hulk TV series for Disney+ named *She-Hulk*. No release date or details are given yet besides the fact that the show is about She-Hulk and Smart Hulk "passing the baton on".

[image: She-Hulk title card]

Lastly, it is worth noting that Red Hulk has almost been introduced into the MCU a couple of times. Firstly, he was considered for *Captain America: Civil War* but dropped due to the fact they already had so many characters.

> "We had so many characters in that movie as it was," Joe Russo tells ComicBook.com. "We consider everything, obviously, but with so many characters in that movie as it was to try and entertain adding another character and to get to the Red Hulk, you have to add a back story. You have to substantiate the narrative to get to that. [Thaddeus Ross], on our list of priorities, he was there sort of as the government's agenda and not to add another complicated super powered character to the mix."
>
> [...]
>
> "If they had given him the narrative space, Red Hulk may have fit," he said. "But if you put a Hulk into a movie like *Captain America: Civil War*, you have to treat him like a weapon of mass destruction."
>
> <sub>[ComicBook.com, Red Hulk And Iron Spider Were Considered For Captain America: Civil War](https://comicbook.com/2016/08/24/red-hulk-and-iron-spider-were-considered-for-captain-america-civ/)</sub>

He was again then considered for *Avengers: Endgame* after the Hulk Snap but this time it was more just Hulk turning red rather than a proper Red Hulk so the idea was scrapped as explained by Christopher Markus:

> “I entertained the idea for about a day.”
>
> “Red Hulk is a completely different thing in the comics. It wound up being, well, really, we’re just saying he changes color. That’s not a character change. If there’s a future for William Hurt as a superhero, he can turn into Red Hulk.”
>
> <sub>[Screen Geek, Red Hulk Almost Showed Up In ‘Avengers: Endgame’](https://www.screengeek.net/2019/08/07/avengers-endgame-red-hulk/)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

*Avengers: Endgame* features the [Merged Hulk](https://hulk.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Hulk_incarnations#Merged.2FProfessor_Hulk).